# Apply CSS to a specific class

Tags: css, class

I want to add specific CSS to the class below. I would like to add cursor: pointer. How would I go about this without adding it to every toggle-transparent class?

```
<h3 class="toggle-transparent navbar-text pull-right">Handbook</h3>
```

Comment: You forgot to paste your code.

Comment: You mean to the element? Qualify it: `h3.toggle-transparent`

Answer (score 2):

If there is only one h3 with `toggle-transparent navbar-text pull-right` classes, then this will do:

```
.toggle-transparent.navbar-text.pull-right {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

I'd recommend adding another class to it if you are using these three specific classes elsewhere.  Something like this might work better

```
<h3 class="toggle-transparent navbar-text pull-right pointer">Handbook</h3> 

.toggle-transparent.pointer {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
h3.toggle-transparent.navbar-text.pull-right { cursor:pointer; }
```

for example

so the h3 tag must have the 3 classes, very specific, but not unique - else you have to add an id or another class